Display a `Drawable`
I'm working with JetPack Compose and I'm trying to display a Drawable (I want to display icons of other applications installed on the device):
val application: ResolveInfo;
val packageManager = LocalContext.current.packageManager;
val iconDrawable: Drawable = application.activityInfo.loadIcon(packageManager) // What to do with this?

I've been trying
Image(BitmapPainter(iconDrawable.toBitmap().asImageBitmap()), "")

but I get the error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: View needs to be laid out before calling drawToBitmap()

How can I display a Drawable ?

Add
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-drawablepainter:<version>" 

and use it like this
@Composable fun DrawDrawable() {
    Image(
        painter = rememberDrawablePainter(drawable = drawable),
        contentDescription = "Content description"
    )
}

For more info refer
:https://google.github.io/accompanist/drawablepainter/
